# Discord - Link sharing meta

Tags: html, discord, meta, sharing

When sharing a link on Discord, it's showing my Email address in the preview.

[image: image sharing preview]

I've looked at the meta tags on the site and see no mention at all of my Email address. Is their a specific tag it requires? I saw that it mentions using a Twitter Card's meta. But that hasn't seemed to have made any difference.

Existing meta....

```
<!-- Favicon(s) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

<!-- Linked In -->
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.mobilerocket.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mobilerocket/assets/img/rocket-social-linkedin.png"/>

<!-- Twitter -->
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://www.mobilerocket.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mobilerocket/assets/img/rocket-social-linkedin.png">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@themobilerockit" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Mobile Apps For Business | North East App Development" />
```

Thanks

Comment: I fear that this is almost not a programming question.

Comment: @Gourav so nothing to do with meta tags? Interesting...

Comment: But the main motive is on the discord software.